# How to update a multichracter delimited field in a file in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to match a certain field and update its data from a file delimited with multiple characters. I'm using this to create an imitation of SQL's UPDATE. This is part of a bigger project to create a mini DBMS with bash.

**What I tried:**

```
sed "s/\^\_\^/:/g" $file_path | cut -d: -f1 | grep -nw SAR | sed "s/\^\_\^/:/g" | cut -d: -f2 | sed -i "s/$match/$update/g"
```

My issue is I am unable to use `sed -i` to update only these specific columns found as you can't pipe into it.

The delimiter being used is : `^_^`

**Example of data file:**

```
'EGP'^_^'Egypt'
'SAR'^_^'Europe'
'SAR'^_^'Europe'
'SAR'^_^'Europe'
'SAR'^_^'Europe'
'Europe'^_^'SAR'
'SAR'^_^'Europe'
'MYR'^_^'Malaysia'
'MYR'^_^'Malasia'
```

my `$match` can be `SAR` for example and `$update` would be `USD`

**Expected change to data file**

```
'EGP'^_^'Egypt'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'Europe'^_^'SAR'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'MYR'^_^'Malaysia'
'MYR'^_^'Malasia'
```

If there is a different approach that is better, that is also welcome as I am fairly new to bash scripting.

Comment: If you have fields `awk` is probably a better option than `sed`. See the `awk` `FS` variable (Field Separator) in the `awk` documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use `awk` here:

```sh
awk -v s="'SAR'" -v q="'USD'" -F'\\^_\\^' -v OFS='^_^' '$1==s {$1=q} 1' file

'EGP'^_^'Egypt'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'Europe'^_^'SAR'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'MYR'^_^'Malaysia'
'MYR'^_^'Malasia'
```

**Explanation:**

- `-v s="'SAR'"` sets command line variable `s='SAR'`
- `-v q="'USD'"` sets command line variable `s='USD'`
- `-F '\\^_\\^'` sets input field separator as `^_^`. We need to escape `^` as that is a special regex meta character and we need to double escape it because we're using it in a string that is later converted to a regexp (field separator).
- `-v OFS='^_^'` sets output field separator to `^_^`
- `$1 == s` compares first field to `'SAR'`
- `$1 = q` sets `$1` to variable `'USD'`

Comment: A bit simpler, maybe: `awk -v s="'SAR'" -v q="'USD'" -F'\\^_\\^' '$1==s {$1=q} 1' file`.

Comment: Thanks, using single quotes around `-F` reduces escaping. However we still need to set `OFS`

Comment: Ooops, yes, I forgot it, sorry.

Comment: Quite elegant, thank you very much! One last question though as I am not that familliar with awk. What does that trailing 1 at the end of the awk script do?

Comment: Trailing `1` (or any non-zero value) prints each line of input.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed you could use `$match` at the start of the string `^`, and change it with `$update`:

```
match="'SAR'"
update="'USD'"
sed "s/^$match\^_\^/$update^_^/" file
```

Output

```
'EGP'^_^'Egypt'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'Europe'^_^'SAR'
'USD'^_^'Europe'
'MYR'^_^'Malaysia'
'MYR'^_^'Malasia'
```

See a [bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexJDnDVkk92DFIXYmrtCAlsSQVyA0NdgFyi1NTFJSK9eNUwKpi4uJj4vRVIGri4uP0lRRsbGwUlNRd3QPUgXx11/TKghJ1LrBZYH5pUX5BKnkCUAZIDCSHRYVvJETANzEnsbI4MxFNCCSi9P8/AA).

Comment: A bit simpler, maybe: `match="'SAR'"; update="'USD'"; sed "s/^$match\\^_\\^/$update^_^/" file`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Using the single quotes in the variables you mean right? That would make it more readable indeed.

Comment: This definitely works, only question is what happens if I want to update the second field? The ^ only matches the start of a given pattern.

Comment: @Stoon If you want to match the nth match, you can use a quantifier and a capture group to skip n fields before matching what you want to replace. It would be like `sed "s/^\(\('[^']*'\^_\^\)\{2\}\)$match\^_\^/\1$update^_^/g" file` See [this example](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexJDnDVkk92DFIXYmrtCAlsSQVyA0NdgFyi1NTFJSK9eNiNGI01KPj1GO11GPi4mPiYjRjqo1iamM0VcDawWL6MYYqEO1x8XH66UoKNjY2ChBzgQLqrqVF@QWpYCZMSOn/fwA) but in that case awk would be a better fit.

Comment: I see, didn't realize you can do that with sed. A bit convoluted but works. I guess I'll proceed with awk like you and the accepted answer suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -v matchvalue="'SAR'" -v updatedvalue="'USD'" '
match($0,"^"matchvalue"\\^_\\^"){
  print updatedvalue"^_^" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Creating 2 variables named `matchvalue` and `updatedvalue` with `'SAR'` and `'USD'` values shown by OP in samples. Then in main program using `match` function to match if a line starts with `'SAR'^_^` then print new value in its place and then print rest of the line, if line doesn't start from `'SAR'^_^` then simply print it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
escaped_delm=$(echo $curr_delim | sed 's/[^^\\]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g; s/\\/\\\\/g')
awk -F"$escaped_delm" -v a_col_update=$update_field -v pick=$p_tmp_field -v a_del="$match" -v a_ins="$insert" -v OFS="$curr_delim" '$pick==a_del {$a_col_update=a_ins} 1' $t_path > tmp && mv tmp $t_path
```

The biggest issue I faced is that I am passing my delimiter `^_^` as a variable to awk. My script assumes that I don't know what the variable is and that it is passed to it at the beginning of the script. This causes an issue, just like the first answer suggested the `-F` option for `awk` thinks that `^` is a regex argument.

This is where the `sed` command I used comes in super handy! It sanitizes the delimiter by escaping any regex meta characters. Would like to thank Ed Morton for the great answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) where I got the `sed` command from.

Hope someone else finds this useful!

My awk variables are:

1. `curr_delim="^_^"`
2. `a_col_update=<column number to be updated>`
3. `pick=<column used to pick the record/row>`
4. `a_del=<field to be updated from picked record/row>`
5. `a_ins=<new value for the picked field>`
6. `OFS="$curr_delim"`